# Opening an Excel application client-side

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, com, interop

I'm trying to use the COM interop assembly to export some data to an Excel workbook for an ASP.NET web application. This works fine in development, since the server and the client are the same machine. However, when deployed, this is not the case. The deployed version does not throw an exception, but it also does not open Excel on the local machine (since ASP.NET is executed server-side, this is pretty obvious).

How do I go about creating an Excel application on the client's machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to generate the excel file server side, then send the bytes to the client using the appropriate MIME type so that the client can figure out how to open it.

Something like this...

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", fileName));
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
```

where `fileName` is the name you want for the file, and `bytes` is the output from your excel generator in `byte[]` form.

Note that this doesn't really force excel open or anything like that, it just presents the content to the client in the best format possible for the client to open it in excel.  The user will have to click "open" and if they have excel installed, it will be the default application to open the file.

If the client doesn't have excel, or their mime types aren't mapped etc, it's not going to work.  Without some crazy activex voodoo (which I don't recommend) you're not going to be able to "open excel for them".

Comment: Side note, COM Interop with the office DLL's is a really bad way to generate excel files on a server.  Furthermore, Office isn't really licensed for that use anyway.  I would highly recommend a library such as NPOI or ExcelLibrary to generate your files.

Comment: This has all been documented in [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office - KB 257757](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757).

Answer (score 2):

DO NOT USE COM INTEROP!!!

There is a much better way:  [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/)

When opening excel on the server it will keep a copy of excel running.  Horrible.  EPPlus will let you create native excel 2007/2010 worksheets with charts and everything.  And without having office installed on the server itself.  We're using it, pretty slick.

If the clients don't have excel 2007 or better, they can download the [compatibility pack from microsoft.](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/products/microsoft-office-compatibility-pack-for-word-excel-and-powerpoint-HA010168676.aspx)

Comment: I've considered using an open source library. The thing that's nice about COM interop is that it's easy to use if you're familiar with writing Excel macros. Is it safe to assume that EPPlus is just as easy to use?

Comment: @Tyler The licensing issues alone should preclude you from using COM Interop with office on a server, and that's not even going into the performance issues Chris mentions above.  Yes you might have to learn a different library to make your files, but that's what you need to do to keep it in the clear.

Comment: @Brook: I'm aware that Interop is not the best solution. At this point I'm just wondering what the best third-party API is.

Comment: @Tyler: that's going to depend on your requirements.  If you're generating Macro's dynamically, you're probably going to have to buy something commercial.  EPPlus can use a file with macro's as a template, but it won't let you manipulate them.  The other open source libs i'm aware of such as ExcelLibrary or NPOI are the same way.  If you're OK with forcing users to have the 2007 compat pack, EPPlus is the most robust.  If not, I like ExcelLibrary, it is pretty simple and lightweight.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give EPPlus a shot.

Comment: While this is an excellent point, which I totally agree with, I don't see how it answers the question of how to open the data in excel on the client....

Comment: @Brook: Sorry, you're right. It was a combination of this answer and yours which solved my problem, but ultimately your response directly answers the question.

Comment: @Tyler: glad this was able to help lead you to a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a big potential security hole, if you ask me!

One approach might be to start an ActiveX Excel control? (ActiveX being just a marketing term for a COM object). I'm not familiar with ASP.NET, so I don't know how this would work over the server/client boundary.

A simpler, and safer approach would be to create a CSV file, and send it through standard http. The user could the open this in Excel. It would be fine for a single worksheet of data, but not for complex things with macros, formatting, etc.

Comment: The problem I'm facing here is, I'd like to have multiple worksheets, formatting, etc.